# WordPress Schedule Event random intervals

Tags: wordpress, events, plugins, cron, schedule

I have scheduled WordPress to run a function in the plugin every 30 mins. Turned out, that it actually runs it every random amount of time, not as it should.

I also tried to configured it to run ever 1 hr as it was more stable with the standard WordPress predefined values, it did work OK for a few hours and then had a break for 4-5hours and back again to run the function but this time with a random intervals again.

The function in turn generate a log file, and based on that I can see when the job was executed, here is the list of log files generated when I scheduled it to run every 30mins:
log name:                    time:
log-propertyList-2015-05-22  17-10-01 (when it was initiated first time)
log-propertyList-2015-05-23  03-20-46
log-propertyList-2015-05-23  03-44-00
log-propertyList-2015-05-23  04-12-18
log-propertyList-2015-05-23  08-03-15
log-propertyList-2015-05-23  10-22-28

When I had it every hour:
log-propertyList-2015-05-20  02-43-06 OK
log-propertyList-2015-05-20  03-43-02 OK
log-propertyList-2015-05-20  04-43-02 OK
log-propertyList-2015-05-20  05-43-06 OK
log-propertyList-2015-05-20  06-43-02 OK
log-propertyList-2015-05-20  07-43-02 OK
log-propertyList-2015-05-20  08-43-02 OK
log-propertyList-2015-05-20  11-51-15 - huge break
log-propertyList-2015-05-20  13-27-03 - huge break

Who knows what it could? 
Please assist.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WordPress scheduled jobs are [activated on user visit](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) (and then checked if the defined time period has passed). So if you defined to be run every 30mins and there are no user visit in that period then your action won't run.

Maybe [this article with replacing WP-cron with real cron jobs](https://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/wordpress/how-to-replace-wordpress-cron-with-a-real-cron-job) can help. It should be applicable to every hosting with a cPanel.